# Parser error when using jQuery-UJS for remote link_to in Rails 3 app: how can I debug this?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to replace the content of a div after clicking on a link using Rails 3, `remote_link :remote => true` and jQuery.

So far, I've been able to get the controller render the correct partial while responding with a 200 HTTP code. I've set some callbacks to find the origin of the problem:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("#follow-link").bind("ajax:before", function() {
        console.log("ajax:before");
    });

    $("#follow-link").bind("ajax:success", function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("ajax:success");
    });

    $("#follow-link").bind("ajax:complete", function() {
        console.log("ajax:complete");
    });

    $("#follow-link").bind("ajax:error", function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("ajax:error");
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

While `before` and `complete` are triggered, `success` is not and `error` outputs "parsererror". The content I get when I inspect the response in Safari's developers tools is a simple string.

Why would it raise a parsererror? How can I get more information about what's causing this error?

Comment: As it's a parse error, could you be expecting JSON or XML and getting HTML, or something like that? If you look under Resources in Safari, you can examine the response. You haven't shown the Ajax call, so it's hard to tell what's happening. jQuery is supposed to "guess" the response type based on MIME type -- it's hard to tell where this might go wrong but again, worth looking at the response to make sure you are sending the same stuff your server declares in the MIME type.

Comment: In the resource header, the request is set to accept `text/javascript` and the response is also `text/javascript`. The call is `<a href="/unfollow/83" data-remote="true" id="follow-link">Unfollow</a>` generated by the Rails helper `link_to "Follow", follow_path(user), :remote => true, :id => "follow-link"`.

Comment: So you are using `rails.js`. It is unclear to me what you are getting back in the "simple string" or what the MIME type is. Pretty clearly, jQuery is attempting to parse this or it is handing it off to Safari's js engine to parse it as script. Either way, that's not the desired effect, right? Look in the Resources tab and in the partial should show up near the bottom. Then when you see the string that was returned, what is that? Also, click on the headers tab of the display window and look at the Request accept header and Response content-type header. These should give you an idea what's up.

Comment: I'm trying to get an existing .html.erb partial rendered. I've read examples that made me use a .js.erb calling the partial: `<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "followings/follow") %>`, which works and gets me the expected response in the resources, but it is still not parsed. When the follow.js.erb only outputs `"test"`, the request is a success. The problem seems to be parsing .html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to propose an answer because comments don't allow for any formatting. Here is is: Something is happening on the server side and jQuery is not getting what you think it is. Here's an excerpt from the jQuery documentation:

> error(jqXHR, textStatus,
>   errorThrown)Function A function to be
>   called if the request fails. The
>   function receives three arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object, a string
>   describing the type of error that
>   occurred and an optional exception
>   object, if one occurred. Possible
>   values for the second argument
>   (besides null) are "timeout", "error",
>   "abort", and "parsererror". When an
>   HTTP error occurs, errorThrown
>   receives the textual portion of the
>   HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or
>   "Internal Server Error."

That implies that your controller may be responding with something other than the expected data. In that controller, try:

```
Rails.logger.debug render_to_string(:partial => "followings/follow")
```

In any case, check your logs to make sure what you think is happening really is happening. Also, write a test to verify this:

```
# controller spec... modify if using Test::Unit
it "sends cool javascript" do
  xhr.post :unfollow, :id => 83, :data-method => "delete"
  response.body should == "some known response"
end
```

Ok, it's a hacky, brittle spec, but it will do until you know where things are going wrong.

Once you get this working, everything else will fall neatly into place.

Comment: The problem was that I was using `format.js` instead of `format.html` in the controller for rendering an html partial. I still don't know why rendering the html partial inside a js would break everything, but now it's working.

Comment: jQuery hands the script off to the browser to eval. It should be unparsable.

Answer (score 12):

I was also getting odd `parsererror`s even though my remote links were correctly pointing to actions with `:format => :js` and my controller actions were correctly using `respond_to` to serve up JSON objects like:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render :json => {:something => "OK"}
  end
end
```

The solution ended up being just dropping this line into my `application.js`:

```
$.ajaxSettings.dataType = "json";
```

By default, it appeared that jQuery was trying to evaluate all responses as `"script"`, which I guess means it was trying to execute it as code—? Dropping this line in once fixed the issue globally.

Comment: Setting `$.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'json';` solved the `parsererror` problem for me, too. I don't know why this is needed, though.

Comment: The reason it is needed is because by default rails.js (or maybe jQuery, not sure actually) is requesting text/javascript (:js) instead of application/json (:json) and it fails to parse because JSON is not valid JavaScript by itself.  Note that you need to update format.js to format.json when you do this as well, although in this simple example it works because there is only one block which counts as the default.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the global `$.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'json';` setting a cleaner solution is to add a `data-type` attribute to the form element. The remote form event handlers will pass this through as the dataType to the jQuery AJAX call, e.g:

```
form_for @subject, :remote => true, :html => {'data-type' => 'json'}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Much cleaner than setting globally or using ajax:complete.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `format.js` use `format.json`

setting `$.ajaxSettings.dataType = 'json';` is liable to cause issues in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to also replace the response format with '.html' instead of '.js' in the controller.

What it does is send the response content type as "html/text" instead of "html/javascript", and this, is somehow acceptable to the response parser.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this is to add .js to the form's action (if you're using a Rails link generator you can add :format => :json).  Then make sure you are responding to json in your controller.

Here's an example of a sign in form configured that way:

```
    <%= form_for User.new, :url => session_path(:user, :format => :json), :html => {:id => "login-form", :class => "well"}, :remote => :true do |f| %>
      <label>Email</label>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
      <label>Password</label>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :remember_me %>
      <%= button_tag "Sign in", :class => "btn", :type => "submit" %><%= image_tag "ajax-loader.gif", :style => "display:none", :id => "login-spinner" %>
    <% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
def create
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ super }
  format.json do
   resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => :failure)
   return sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to update the contents of a DIV using a normal JQuery AJAX call using the HTML output from a rails controller action, you need to tell JQuery what dataType to expect on the response, so that it will not parse the response as javascript and give you the parsererror you describe.

```
$.ajax({ url: "/blah", 
  contentType: "text/javascript", dataType: "html",
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/javascript');    
  }, 
  success: function(data) {
    $('your-div').html(data);
  }
});
```

This would then be compatible with a controller action that uses the respond_to block:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    # This would be a normal render of your template.
  }
  format.js {
    # This would be a render of your template, as HTML, but only for your AJAX requests.
    # We might use this to avoid including the layout of our template.
    render :layout => nil 
  }
end
```